# Formatting tags break stacked feature-linked annotations with Maplex

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, annotation, maplex

I have a stacked feature-linked annotation, with one of the fields using a formatting tag. The annotation is fine when it is created, however all the lines collapse onto one line when a change is made to the linked feature. A related bug is logged on Esri's website (http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDc4OTQ4), but the stacked label collapses with any formatting text. Here is an example of the annotation expression:

```
def FindLabel ( [field1], [field2], [field3], [field4] ):
  return [field1] + " " + "<FNT size='6'>" + [field2] + "</FNT>" + " " + [field3] + " " + [field4]
```

edit: Esri support has recognized this as a bug.

Comment: Is the missing + in between the last set of quotes and [field4] a typo from when you brought it here or actually in the code?

Comment: @Kevin It was a typo when I brought it here. It is not actually in the code.

Comment: Added bounty to the question.

Comment: The bug description says it's fixed in 10.1 SP1, do you encounter it with 10.2?

Comment: Yes. I've tried it on 10.2 and 10.1 with SP1 and had the problem both times. Can anyone else recreate this?